# javafx giving me multiple errors

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX program with the simple GUI created. However whenever I run it it gives me an error that doesn't seem to be able to be fixed.

Here is the code:

```
package me.sam.algorithm;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
  class SchoolDay extends Application {

public void start(Stage Primarystage) {
           //main menu
           VBox menu = new VBox();
           HBox mini1= new HBox();
           HBox mini2= new HBox();
           menu.setPadding(new Insets(15,12,15,12));
           menu.setSpacing(20);
           mini1.setSpacing(3);
           mini2.setSpacing(3);
           Scene mainm = new Scene(menu, 500, 500, Color.BLACK);
           Label s1 = new Label("What day is it?");
           Label s2 = new Label("Is it late or regular start?");
           Label s3 = new Label("If you've filled everything out, press start!");
           Button beg = new Button("Start!");
           ToggleButton l1 = new ToggleButton("Regular Start");
           ToggleButton l2 = new ToggleButton("Late Start");
           ToggleButton d1 = new ToggleButton("Day 1"); 
           ToggleButton d2 = new ToggleButton("Day 2"); 
           ToggleButton d3 = new ToggleButton("Day 3"); 
           ToggleButton d4 = new ToggleButton("Day 4"); 
           ToggleButton d5 = new ToggleButton("Day 5"); 
           ToggleButton d6 = new ToggleButton("Day 6"); 
           ToggleGroup togg1 = new ToggleGroup();
           ToggleGroup togg2 = new ToggleGroup();
           d1.setToggleGroup(togg1);
           d2.setToggleGroup(togg1);
           d3.setToggleGroup(togg1);
           d4.setToggleGroup(togg1);
           d5.setToggleGroup(togg1);
           d6.setToggleGroup(togg1);
           l1.setToggleGroup(togg2);
           l2.setToggleGroup(togg2);
           mini2.getChildren().addAll(l1,l2);
           mini1.getChildren().addAll(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);
           menu.getChildren().addAll(s1,mini1,s2,mini2,s3,beg);
           menu.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
           mini1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
           mini2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
           Primarystage.setTitle("MICDS Day");
           Primarystage.setScene(mainm);
           Primarystage.show();
           //main scene

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }}
    `
```

The reason why I'm posting here is that this error wasn't here before I began extracting the modena.css file from the jfxrt.jar. Did I screw something up in the JDK/JRE or is it a code error. Also, is it even fixable? I've already tried uninstalling jdk and reinstalling it. Just in case its important, I use eclipse neon IDE.

Here is the error it gives me no matter what I do:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application i        instance: class me.samJFX.SchoolDay
at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.samJFX.SchoolDay.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
```

Comment: What do you mean with: "I began extracting the modena.css file from the jfxrt.jar"?

Comment: change `class SchoolDay` to `public class SchoolDay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `SchoolDay` class `public`. `Application.launch` cannot access the constructor of non-`public` classes which leads to this exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: me.samJFX.SchoolDay.<init>()
```

Also fix the package (`me.samJFX` != `me.sam.algorithm`).

Furthermore the compiler will complain about the last `}`, since the class was already closed by the previous `}`.

(I don't know how you even got to the point where you could run this code with the last 2 issues.)